# Append dynamically created row to table

Tags: jquery, html, append

I want to add this row to tbody of a table using jquery

My code :

```
<tr class="odd gradeX">
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
<th>text</th>
<td>text</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#AppointmentsDeleteModal">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried like:

```
var table_row  = '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
table_row += '<td>'+appointmentObj.service_name+'</td>';
table_row += '<td>'+appointmentIdObj.appointment_quantity+'</td>';
table_row += '<td>'+appointmentObj.service_rate+'</td>';
table_row +=    '<td>'+parseInt(appointmentIdObj.appointment_quantity)
*parseInt(appointmentIdObj.service_rate)+'</td>';
table_row += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#AppointmentsDeleteModal">Delete</button></td></tr>'

$('#mytable tbody').append(table_row);
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: do you have 'tbody' in your table?

Comment: yes i have. am getting the error like Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a syntax error in your code:

```
table_row += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#AppointmentsDeleteModal">Delete</button></td></tr>'
```

should be in one line:

```
table_row += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AppointmentsDeleteModal">Delete</button></td></tr>'
```

Comment: It worked! So how can i add click events to the delete button using thee class btn

Comment: `$(".btn").on("click", function() {/*todo on button click*/})`

Answer (score 1):

try

`$('#mytable').append($(table_row));`

Comment: No need to use like this, .append(table_row) is enough http://jsfiddle.net/ThrS9/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the row to table:

```
 $('#mytable').append(table_row);
```

Comment: Actually am getting syntax error while appending the code.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this :

```
$('.odd:last').after(table_row);
```

this will append row after last row of your table. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

As VolkanUlukut pointed out. It seems like your problem may just be that you're adding line breaks within a single line of your JS.

So:

```
table_row +=    '<td>'+parseInt(appointmentIdObj.appointment_quantity)
*parseInt(appointmentIdObj.service_rate)+'</td>';
table_row += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#AppointmentsDeleteModal">Delete</button></td></tr>'
```

becomes:

```
table_row += '<td>'+parseInt(appointmentIdObj.appointment_quantity)*parseInt(appointmentIdObj.service_rate)+'</td>';
table_row += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AppointmentsDeleteModal">Delete</button></td></tr>'
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Wq6Uu/ which is essentially your code, but working due to the line breaks being removed.